# Modificar ventana en PyQt desde otra ventana

Tags: pyqt, popup, qt-designer, qmainwindow

Quiero hacer desde estas 2 ventanas creadas con el QtDesigner que al apretar un boton en la secuandaria, se me cambie el texto en la primera. No lo estoy pudiendo lograr. Dejo el codigo abajo para ver si me pueden ayudar.

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

class VentanaPrincipal(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(VentanaPrincipal, self).__init__()
        loadUi('Principal.ui', self)
        self.boton1.clicked.connect(self.abrirObjeto1)

    def abrirObjeto1(self):
        self.hide()
        otraventana=Objeto1(self)
        otraventana.show()
    
    
class Objeto1(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Objeto1, self).__init__(parent)
        loadUi('Secundaria.ui', self)
        self.uno.clicked.connect(VentanaPrincipal.texto1.setText("uno"))
        self.uno.clicked.connect(self.abrirVentanaPrincipal)
        
    def abrirVentanaPrincipal(self):
        self.parent().show()
        self.close()

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
main = VentanaPrincipal()
main.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Puedes poner los archivos 'ui'?

Comment: no sabria como hacer lo de poner las ui aca

Comment: En el designer no puedes ir a la ventana de edición? Si es así, copia en texto y pégalo aquí